# Algebraic number field without abelian extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

What are examples of algebraic extensions $K / \Bbb Q$ such that $K$ has no non-trivial (finite or infinite) abelian extension?
For instance, can we have $K \neq \overline{\Bbb Q}$?

I think that we must have $\sqrt d, e^{2 \pi i /n} \in K$ for any $d,n \in \Bbb Z^*$ (in particular $K$ cannot be finite over $\Bbb Q$ I think). But typically the maximal abelian extension of $\Bbb Q$ does have non-trivial abelian extensions!

Comment: Does Kummer theory help?

Comment: I guess any field that is closed under taking roots should work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Uchida paper introduces without comment a Galois extension $\Omega/\mathbf Q$ which "has no abelian extension". This triggered in my mind the suspicion that the considerations about the Schur multiplier of a perfect group were perhaps irrelevant. And indeed they are.

An infinite extension as $\Omega$ must contain $K_1 :=\mathbf Q^{ab}$, and recursively, the chain of ascending extensions defined by  $K_{i+1} = K_i^{ab}$. In terms of Galois groups, this means that one has to introduce the *derived series* of $G_{\mathbf Q}$ defined by $G_{\mathbf Q}^{i+1}=[G_{\mathbf Q}^i,G_{\mathbf Q}^i]$, and the problem of the existence of $\Omega \neq \bar {\mathbf Q}$ is equivalent to the question whether the derived series stabilizes non trivially. The Wikipedia article on derived series states : *For a finite group, the derived series terminates in a **perfect** group, which may or may not be trivial. For an infinite group, the derived series need not terminate at a finite stage, and one can continue it to infinite ordinal numbers via transfinite recursion, thereby obtaining the transfinite derived series, which eventually terminates at the **perfect core** of the group.* That's all we needed.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :-) $$ $$ 1) What is the Galois group of $K_2$ over $K_1$, in terms of the derived subgroups $G_{\bf Q}^i$ ?I'm not sure since $K_2$ is not Galois over $\bf Q$. $$ $$ 2) And so is the perfect core [= largest perfect subgroup] $H$ of $G_Q$ trivial or not (as closed subgroup of $G_Q$)? $$ $$ 3) I guess that you are saying that $H = Gal(\bar Q / \Omega)$ with $\Omega$ without any abelian extension, right? (I guess that there might be other $\Omega$ with this properties, also).

Comment: 1) Since $K_{i +1}$ is the maximal abelian extension of $K_i$, it is stable under Galois action, hence $K_{i+1}$ is Galois over Q. For simplicity,  drop the index Q , so that $G^0=G=G_Q$, and put $G_{i}=G^î/G^{i+1}$. Then $Gal(K_2/K_1)$ is an extension of $G_0$ by $G_1$, etc.  2) H is the perfect core of $G_Q$, but since we don't know completely $G_Q$, we don't know if H is trivial or not. I guess that in the papers of Neukirch, Uchida, etc. they just take into account the *possibility* of a non trivial H  3) No, there is no other $\Omega$, remember that $\Omega$ is the "limit" of the $K_i$'s

Comment: Thank you ; I think that together with your nice comments, I can accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let us stick to finite extensions of $\mathbf Q$. To put your question in context, recall the *inverse Galois problem* : is every finite group $G$ realizable as the Galois group of a normal extension of $\mathbf Q$ ? The most general positive result is the famous theorem of Shafarevitch (1954) : yes if $G$ is solvable. But this result is in the opposite direction w.r.t. your question, because a solvable extension is obtained by "piling up" abelian extensions, in more mathematical terms, in solving successive *embedding problems* with abelian kernels.

In the direction of your question (no abelian subextension), the most natural approach would be to try to realize *non abelian simple groups* (the complete list of these is known) as Galois groups over $\mathbf Q$. For example, among the classical families such as $PSL_n (q)$ or $PSU_n (q)$, the realization is possible when $q=p^f$ is small w.r.t. $n$. But for instance the problem remains open for $PSL_2 (5^f)$ if $f>2$, $PSL_2 (3^f)$ if $f>3$, $PSL_3 (3^f)$ if $f>2$, $PSL_4 (2^f)$ if $f>1$. On the other hand, one knows how to realize all the simple sporadic groups except the Mathieu group $M_{23}$.

One larger and deeper approach would be to study the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf Q$ using topological/geometric methods (coverings of the projective line $\mathbf P^1$, Hurwitz spaces, Grothendieck's "dessins d'enfants",...). An accessible account is Pierre Debes' report, "Autour du problème inverse de Galois", Bicentenaire de la naissance d'Evariste Galois, IHP-SMF, October 2011.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear: I wanted $K/\Bbb Q$ such that if $L/K$ is abelian then $L=K$. So I don't understand why you are talking about "subextensions".

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood "subextension of K" instead of "extension of K", but this was perhaps because your question doesn't make sense : any number field K admits non trivial abelian extensions, which are described by class field theory. In particular cases, e.g . when K contains the group mu_n of  n-th roots of unity (this is always the case for n=2), Kummer theory (which is purely algebraic) even tells you that the Galois group over K of the maximal abelian extension of exponent n of K is isomorphic to Hom (K*/K*^n, mu_n)

Comment: Yes, but what about infinite extension $K / \Bbb Q$ (as mentioned in my question)?

Comment: Is it possible to have $K \neq \overline{\Bbb Q}$ (infinite algebraic over $\Bbb Q$), without any abelian extension?

Comment: Sorry, do you have an answer to my above comment? Thank you ver much!

Comment: Your original question is a difficult one. In general, finite and infinite algebraic extensions of Q seem to behave quite differently. One example: as I said, the main "conjecture" of inverse Galois theory is that every finite group should be realizable as a Galois group over Q. But on the other hand, it follows easily from the Kronecker-Weber theorem that an abelian profinite group of rank 2 without torsion is not realizable. Back to your question, all I can suggest is to consider an infinite algebraic extension K as the fixed field of a closed subgroup H of $G_Q$.

Comment: Then "your" property  is that H has no non trivial quotient, i.e. H = closure of its commutator subgroup, i.e. H is a *perfect* group. We can get a hold on such an H via its Schur mutiplier $M(H):=H_2(H, Z)$. If a group H is described by generators and relations, say H = F/R (with F free), then $M(H) = (R \cap [F,F])/[F,R]$. If moreover H is perfect, you have an exact sequence $1 \to M(H)= R/[F,R] \to [F,F]/[F,R] \to H \to 1$ . A starting point would be Tate's thm. that $M(G_Q)$ is trivial (this is true for the algebraic closure of any number field).

Comment: The next natural step would be to try to catch M(H) from this, but in general, for a subgroup H of a group G, the image of the restriction map $M(G) \to M(H)$ is not well known. I'm stuck here for the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. Would you mind to copy them into your answer? Moreover, I was confused because [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1240433915) is talking about a Galois extension $\Omega / \Bbb Q$ that "has no abelian extension", without making any further comment. Do they mean it should be easy to find such $\Omega$ (which is my question)?

Comment: Moreover, would you know an answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689504/p-primary-part-of-an-abelian-group ? Thank you :)